# Tkinter, Matplotlib, py2exe: Import Error: DLL load failed when running .exe

Tags: python, matplotlib, executable, py2exe, pyinstaller

I have a python program called UIMaster.py that I am turning into an executable using py2exe. When I run the setup.py file in the terminal, it is creating the build and dist folders and is including a UIMaster.exe file in the dist folder, however; when I double click it the terminal window pops up then waits a second and writes some text (closes too quickly to read) then closes. However, when I run my python program with python, everything works. I am not 100% sure why this is happening. I am using matplotlib and I think that this may be causing the problem. I am sure I need to exclude some things from the options and possibly add somethign to the data files, but am not sure if this is right. When I go into the terminal and cd dist and then run UIMaster.exe, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "UIMaster.py", line 7, in <module>
    File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 1100, in <module>
    File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 947, in rc_params
    File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 789, in matplotlib_fname
    File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 325, in wrapper
    File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 693, in _get_data_path_cached
    File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 689, in _get_data_path
RuntimeError: Could not find the matplotlib data files
```

The following is the code in my setup.py:

```
    from distutils.core import setup
    import zmq.libzmq
    import py2exe
    import numpy
    setup(
        console = ['UIMaster.py'],
        zipfile='lib/library.zip',
        options={
            'py2exe': {
                'includes': ['zmq.backend.cython'],
                'excludes': ['zmq.libzmq'],
                'dll_excludes': ['libzmq.pyd'],
            }
        },
        data_files=[
            ('lib', (zmq.libzmq.__file__,))
        ]
    )
```

I have also tried the following and I still get the same error message:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import zmq.libzmq
import py2exe
import numpy
import matplotlib
import pylab
setup(
    console = ['UIMaster.py'],
    zipfile='lib/library.zip',
    options={
        'py2exe': {
            'includes': ['zmq.backend.cython'],
            'excludes': ['zmq.libzmq','_gtkagg', '_tkagg'],
            'dll_excludes': ['libzmq.pyd'],
        }
    },
    data_files=[
        ('lib', (zmq.libzmq.__file__,),matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles() )
    ]
)
```

At last, I tried the following and got the same error message:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import zmq.libzmq
import py2exe
import matplotlib
setup(
    console = ['UIMaster.py'],
    zipfile='lib/library.zip',
    options={
        'py2exe': {
            'packages': ['matplotlib', 'pytz'],
            'includes': ['zmq.backend.cython'],
            'excludes': ['zmq.libzmq','_gtkagg', '_tkagg'],
            'dll_excludes': ['libzmq.pyd','libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                                     'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
                                     'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll',
                                     'libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                                     'libglib-2.0-0.dll',
                                     'libcairo-2.dll',
                                     'libpango-1.0-0.dll',
                                     'libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll',
                                     'libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll',
                                     'libglade-2.0-0.dll',
                                     'libgmodule-2.0-0.dll',
                                     'libgthread-2.0-0.dll',
                                     'QtGui4.dll', 'QtCore.dll',
                                     'QtCore4.dll'],
        }
    },
    data_files=[
        ('lib', (zmq.libzmq.__file__,),matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),)
    ]
)
```

Note: I am also having to adjust for the zmq module

I would like to use py2exe over pyinstaller just because I am not familiar with pyinstaller but if someone can give me some pointers on pyinstaller then I am down to use that for my executable conversion.

**EDIT: I attempted to use pyinstaller and I keep getting**

```
IOError Errno[22] invalid mode <'rb'> or filename: "
```

Is there anything else I need to do to get the executable up and running? I am already generating the build and dist folders, but have no clue why the program isin't popping up from the executable. Thanks guys!

**Edit: when using matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles()**

**The following error is produced when I go to the dist folder and run the .exe:**

```
  File "UIMaster.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\pyplot.pyc", line 109, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\backends\__init__.pyc", line 32, in pylab_setup
  File "matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4agg.pyc", line 17, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.pyc", line 18, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.pyc", line 31, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.pyc", line 91, in <module>
  File "PyQt4\QtCore.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "PyQt4\QtCore.pyc", line 10, in __load
  ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Which *python* and *matplotlib* versions are you using? Try editing the `data_files` option as follows: `data_files=[('lib', [zmq.libzmq.__file__])] + matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles()`.

Comment: It ran properly when I added that but now I am getting the following error:
(I am going to put this in an edit in the bottom so that it is easy to see)

Comment: @Yoel my python is 2.7 and my matplotlib is version 1.4.3